# Where and how can I run composer commands?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm kinda lost with Composer and the documentation isnt really helping me. I bascially want to install Laravel but I dont know where I need to run the commands and how.

I've installed composer via the exe on a windows PC that runs XAMPP.

For Example this command:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

How can I run this command? In the windows console? And does it matter where?

Comment: You run it from the command line: on Windows, that's the Windows Console

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I tried it earlier and it didnt work...anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to htdocs folder and right click on mouse then you will see one option called

**use composer here**
click on that then cmd will open
[image]

then you can use composer commands like

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

this will create laravel setup.

To perform other commands like
compose install

composer update

php artisan commands

you need to right click on project and use composer here then only you can perform composer install,composer update, php artisan and all .

Comment: I just want to add that this is the easiest way to install it: composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 5.0 --prefer-dist

Comment: @Gintoki .ya this is simple one

Answer (score 0):

You should actually go with a good console on windows. Try `gitbash`. (https://msysgit.github.io/) It has one of the best consoles.

If you still want to use composer from `cmd`, just type composer and it will work (provided you have set correct path).