# how to run composer commands for laravel in mac os?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am new to mac os.i have installed laravel in mamp server using manually not using composer.also installed composer but i dont know how to run commands like php artisan and all.

in windows i can easily point to composer like as i given answer to this question

[Where and how can I run composer commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849139/where-and-how-can-i-run-composer-commands/31849213#31849213)

please help me how to in mamp server ?
thank you in advance

Updated::

```
Usage:
 command [options] [arguments]

Options:
 --help (-h)           Display this help message
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version
 --ansi                Force ANSI output
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question
 --profile             Display timing and memory usage information
 --working-dir (-d)    If specified, use the given directory as working directory.

Available commands:
 about            Short information about Composer
 archive          Create an archive of this composer package
 browse           Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
 clear-cache      Clears composer's internal package cache.
 clearcache       Clears composer's internal package cache.
 config           Set config options
 create-project   Create new project from a package into given directory.
 depends          Shows which packages depend on the given package
 diagnose         Diagnoses the system to identify common errors.
 dump-autoload    Dumps the autoloader
 dumpautoload     Dumps the autoloader
 global           Allows running commands in the global composer dir ($COMPOSER_HOME).
 help             Displays help for a command
 home             Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
 info             Show information about packages
 init             Creates a basic composer.json file in current directory.
 install          Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
 licenses         Show information about licenses of dependencies
 list             Lists commands
 remove           Removes a package from the require or require-dev
 require          Adds required packages to your composer.json and installs them
 run-script       Run the scripts defined in composer.json.
 search           Search for packages
 self-update      Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
 selfupdate       Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
 show             Show information about packages
 status           Show a list of locally modified packages
 suggests         Show package suggestions
 update           Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
 validate         Validates a composer.json and composer.lock
CPU664:~ narendrab$ php artisan
Could not open input file: artisan
CPU664:~ narendrab$
```

Comment: Are you using mamp or you have installled standalone php-mysql-apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mac os, you can easily install composer globally by

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then you can just use command `composer` everywhere without specifying full path. You have to use full path for MAMP php since php comes with mac will be default.

**Edit**: run artisan command within the project directory.

[image]

Comment: @Harikrishnan.thank you for the answer iyour fist command works .i tried second command and run the php artisan but it wont work

Comment: if i run mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer then it give error like no such file directory ? and if i run composer then it shows many commands that i will update in my question soon